# facebook share permission from android app

Tags: java, android, facebook, share

I  need to share content on `facebook` from my android app. i could login and retrieve use profile info but i couldn't share post. `shareDialog.registerCallback` not executing in my case.
For `Facebook` share from my app, should i need to give write Permission? If yes, when to give?

My login and share code,

```
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    ShareDialog shareDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(MainActivity.this);
                        shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {

                                if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                                    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new   ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                            .setContentTitle("Share on fb")

                                            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"))
                                            .build();

                                    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                    }
                });

               //     LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent   data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

the way i wanted is like when click on share button(below image) it should login and share on facebook , i think i should use my own custom interface for that.

[image]

Comment: no you don't need the publish_action permission when you use the ShareDialog. could you please post your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Check this link http://www.learn2crack.com/2015/06/android-facebook-sdk-implementation.html

Comment: please see i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need publish_actions permission for that. Try this code.

```
ShareDialog shareDialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {


            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                shareDialog = new ShareDialog(MainActivity.this);
                shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {

                        if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                            ShareLinkContent linkContent = new   ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                    .setContentTitle("Share on fb")

                                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"))
                                    .build();

                            shareDialog.show(linkContent);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {

            }
        });

       //     LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email","publish_actions"));
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent   data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

then you need to create `ShareOpenGraphObject`.

```
// Create an object
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
    .putString("og:type", "books.book")
    .putString("og:title", "A Game of Thrones")
    .putString("og:description", "In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.")
    .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
    .build();
```

then you will have to create action

```
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
    .setActionType("books.reads")
    .putObject("book", object)
    .build();
```

then you will have to make content

```
 ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
    .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
    .setAction(action)
    .build();
```

then

```
ShareDialog.show(activityOrFragment, content);
```

Note Follow code is copied from facebook developer site. Follow this link for more [guidance](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/android)